# Android Facebook get email address of logged in through access token

Tags: android, facebook, email, access-token

In my app, I have allowed users to signup through Facebook. When user logged in, I get access token. Now I want to get email address of the user. How to get that?

Comment: go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403417/fetch-facebook-user-data) link

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all add permission

```
public static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {"email"};

String response=authenticatedFacebook.request("me");
JSONObject obj = Util.parseJson(response);
useremail=obj.getString("email");
```

where authenticatedFacebook is Facebook object.

Util will available along with Facebook SDK.

Ensure that you gave **Email permission**.

Comment: do i need a "built for mobile" facebook app to get user data from facebook(if he is logged in) or "built for web" is enough. because i already have a facebook web app, can i use that APP ID???

Comment: @Archie.bpgc  I don't have idea about Web Application.. But i think we can use same App Id for both Web and Mobile

Comment: Util class is now deprecated. Better to `user.getInnerJSONObject().getString("email");`